# login as Admin and normal user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
database hs_hr_users

user_name    user_password     is_admin
admin          qwe123            Yes
999999         123qwe            No
```

here I have checklongin for normal user only and it working. But I need to login as admin using column `is_admin = 'Yes'`

checklogin.php

```
$host="localhost"; // test local
$username="ess_las_admin"; // Mysql username 
$password="esslasadmin"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="ess_las_admin"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="hs_hr_users"; // Table name user
$tbl_name2 ="hs_hr_employee" ; //
$db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); 
$link = mysql_select_db($db_name,$db);
ob_start();

// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = md5(stripslashes($mypassword));
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name a, $tbl_name2 b WHERE a.emp_number=b.emp_number AND a.user_name='$myusername' and a.user_password='$mypassword' 
        AND (
        b.work_station = '14' 
        OR  b.work_station = '1'
        OR  b.work_station = '15'
        OR  b.work_station = '16'
        OR  b.work_station = '17'
        OR  b.work_station = '18'
        OR  b.work_station = '19'
        OR  b.work_station = '20'
        OR  b.work_station = '21'
        OR  b.work_station = '22'
        OR  b.work_station = '23'
        OR  b.work_station = '24'
        OR  b.work_station = '25'
        OR  b.work_station = '27'
        OR  b.work_station = '28'


        )";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
session_start();
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['user_name_eprofile'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['user_password'] = $mypassword;


//session_register("myusername");
//session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:dashboard.php");
}
else {
//echo "Wrong Username or Password";
header("Location: login.php?error=1");
}

mysql_close($link);
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

All the data for admin and normal user is in same table. But, column `is_admin = Yes/No` that differentiate between both. If user login as admin, will go `header:location:admin_search.php` which is admin page. If user login as normal user, will go `header:location:dashboard.php`.

Comment: `stripslashes` does not protect against SQL injection. People used to suggest `addslashes` but that doesn't do the job either. You shouldn't `md5` an escaped password.

Comment: @Dagon now checklogin.php only can be login by normal user. how to make checklogin.php can differentiate user as admin or normal user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this :

```
if($count==1){
session_start();
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['user_name_eprofile'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['user_password'] = $mypassword;
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['is_admin'] = $row['is_admin'];
```

and do whatever you want with `$_SESSION['is_admin']`.

In your case, for the redirection :

```
if ($_SESSION['is_admin']=="Yes") { 
    header("location:admin_search.php");
} else {
    header("location:dashboard.php");
}
```

Also another suggestion, change `$sql="SELECT * FROM...` to `$sql="SELECT is_admin FROM...`

**BUT**

**Warning**   **Warning**
MYSQL_ FUNCTIONS ARE DEPRECATED
`mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: I try your code, i got this Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\eprofile\checklogin.php on line 60. line 60 is $_SESSION['is_admin'] = $row("is_admin");